# Duplicates not being linked when using alternate link text

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, linked-questions

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684484/android-i-cant-see-bold-spanned-text-in-some-cases), kleopatra has pointed out a duplicate question in the comments but has embedded the link and used custom text to describe it. On the right hand side, there was no `Linked` section until I posted a comment that contained the link in non-embedded format.

Is this behaviour correct or is this a bug that needs to be fixed? Marking it as a bug for now.

Answer (score 4):

The possible duplicate comments that get automatically generated upon voting to close do not get linked at the right-hand side until it actually gets closed as a duplicate, at which point the comment gets automatically deleted as well.

As far as if this is expected behavior: it could be that automatically generated links don't go through the normal "link these questions together" process as normally posted comments, or they could have good reasons as to why they don't want them linked yet. Likely the first reason, as editing the generated comment in any way causes it to become linked as normal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll leave the question tagged as a bug for now until we hear back from one of the developers.